# How to invalidate the block list cache?

Tags: 8, blocks, caching

I need to invalidate the block list cache each time a new configuration entity is created, this is because I have a derivative block to handle dynamically one block for each of my configuration entities. I tried to invalidate the block list with the following code

```
Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache::invalidateTags(['block_list']);
```

But when I go to see available blocks I'm not able to see my new block until I clean all the caches on the site.

Usually, when I need to invalidate entity lists from the cache I use the `ENTITY-NAME_list` tag to do it but this time is not working, maybe I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearing the cache not only invalidates the render cache, but also a lot of other caches. For example all plugin manager discovery caches.

In this case you probably need to invalidate the cache of the block plugin manager:

```
\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')->clearCachedDefinitions();
```

Comment: Nice answer, I will keep this in mind for the future.